# How Spring Integration ServiceActivator Return Types work?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

When you add a [@ServiceActivator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/annotation/ServiceActivator.html) annotation on a method, that method can have different return types which seem to have different implications for the service:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "..", outputChannel = "..")
public T messageReceiver() {...}
```

Where T could be

- `void`
- `Object`
- `MessageHandler`

How does the ServiceActivator differ based on the return type? I am specifically wondering about the line in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/annotation/ServiceActivator.html) that says:

> Return values from the annotated method may be of any type. If the return value is not a Message, a reply Message will be created with that object as its payload.

But I'm not following this because I've seen people return MessageHandlers from their ServiceActivator-annotated methods, and they don't want their MessageHandlers to be wrapped as a payload right?

Like this:

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sendAsyncChannel", autoStartup="false")
public MessageHandler sendAsyncHandler() {
     return // some MessageHandler
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are pointing is a *Messaging Annotations on `@Bean`*. This is a bit different story and it implies not related to *POJO method invocation* aspect.

We use that `@ServiceActivator` on the `MessageHandler` `@Bean` to register an `EventDrivenConsumer` endpoint for the provided `MessageHandler`, when the POJO method style, creates a `MethodInvokingMessageHandler` for the marked with this `@ServiceActivator` method.

Please, see more info in the Reference Manual:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.9.RELEASE/reference/html/overview.html#programming-tips
and:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.9.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations_on_beans